# Writing the word equivalent of a check (cheque) amount

Tags: java, beginner, recursion, converting, numbers-to-words

I am looking for feedback on a solution to the following problem posed from a book that I'm working through (*Java: How To Program* 9th Edition):

> Continuing the discussion in Exercise 16.20, we reiterate the
>   importance of designing check-writing systems to prevent alteration of
>   check amounts. One common security method requires that the amount be
>   written in numbers and spelled out in words as well. Even if someone
>   is able to alter the numerical amount of the check, it’s extremely
>   difficult to change the amount in words. Write an application that
>   inputs a numeric check amount that’s less than £1000 and writes the
>   word equivalent of the amount. For example, the amount 112.43 should
>   be written as
>
> ONE hundred TWELVE and 43 pence

I'm interested in solutions which cover the areas I have studied so far, those being:

> 1. Introduction to Computers and Java
> 2. Introduction to Java Applications
> 3. Introduction to Classes, Objects, Methods and Strings
> 4. Control Statements: Part 1
> 5. Control Statements: Part 2
> 6. Methods: A Deeper Look
> 7. Arrays and ArrayLists
> 8. Classes and Objects: A Deeper Look
> 9. Object-Oriented Programming: Inheritance
> 10. Object-Oriented Programming: Polymorphism
> 11. Exception Handling: A Deeper Look
> 12. GUI Components: Part 1 (Swing)
> 13. Strings, Characters and Regular Expressions

I have been a bit naughty by jumping ahead of the text to use a little recursion within the `readMe()` method.  I figured from the description of recursion that the line of code in question would behave this way and I was right.

I can't help feeling that the way I have implemented the `readMe()` method is somewhat messy and I can see that it would not scale very well beyond £1000 or four digits.  Is there a simpler way of doing this?  All forms of feedback are welcome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCheckAmount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    String userInput;

    boolean correctInput = false;

    do
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter an amount below 1000" );
        userInput = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        if( userInput.indexOf( '.' ) < 0 && validateAmount( userInput ) )   // no decimal point
        {
            correctInput = true;
            readMe( userInput );
        }
        if( userInput.indexOf( '.' ) > 0 && validatePointAmount( userInput ) )  // decimal point
        {
            correctInput = true;
            String[] tokens = userInput.split( "\\." );
            readMe( tokens[ 0 ] );
            System.out.printf( "and " );
            readMe( tokens[ 1 ] );
            System.out.println( "pence" );
        }
    }while( !correctInput );
}

public static boolean validatePointAmount( String amount )
{
    return amount.matches( "\\d{0,3}.?\\d{0,2}" );
}

public static boolean validateAmount( String amount )
{
    return amount.matches( "\\d{0,3}" );
}

public static void readMe( String amount )
{
    String[] oneThruNineteen = { "NULL", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX",
                            "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE",
                            "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",
                            "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN" };

    String[] theDecades = { "NULL", "NULL", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FOURTY", "FIFTY",
                            "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY" };

    int theLength = amount.length();

    switch( theLength )
    {
        case 3:     // 3 digits
            System.out.printf( "%s ", oneThruNineteen[ Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 0 ) ) ] );
            System.out.printf( "hundred " );
            int testMe = Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 1 ) );
            if( testMe < 2 )            // if tens unit in the teens
                System.out.printf( "%s ", oneThruNineteen[ Integer.parseInt( amount.substring( 1, 3 ) ) ] );
            else                        // if tens unit twenty or higher
            {
                String feedMe = amount.substring( 1 , 3 );
                readMe( feedMe );       // recursion I presume? feedback for 2 digits
            }
            break;
        case 2:     // 2 digits
            int testMe2 = Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 0 ) );
            if( testMe2 < 2 )           // if tens unit in the teens
                System.out.printf( "%s ", oneThruNineteen[ Integer.parseInt( amount ) ] );
            else                        // if tens unit twenty or higher
            {
                System.out.printf( "%s ", theDecades[ Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 0 ) ) ] );
                int testMe3 = Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 1 ) );
                if( testMe3 > 0 )       // if next digit is higher than 0, otherwise you get TWENTY NULL for 20 etc
                    System.out.printf( "%s ", oneThruNineteen[ Character.getNumericValue( amount.charAt( 1 ) ) ] );
            }
            break;
        case 1:     // just the 1 digit
            System.out.printf( "%s ", oneThruNineteen[ Integer.parseInt( amount ) ] );
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check out this Stack Overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3911982/300257

Comment: Also see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6780/9357 and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30525/9357.

Answer (score 7):

Yes! Your code is more complicated than it needs to be.

- You treat the String as a String instead of first parsing it as a number and treating it as a number. It is more complicated to treat chars than numbers when you want to use them as numbers.
- You have some code duplication near the logic of `if (testMe < 2) ...`
- Instead of printing directly, it is better to return a String and let the caller print

Here is a method I came up with, that returns a string:

```
static String[] oneThruNineteen = { "NULL", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX",
        "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE",
        "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",
        "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN" };

static String[] theDecades = { "NULL", "NULL", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FOURTY", "FIFTY",
        "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY" };
public static String numToStr(int amount) {
    String str = "";
    if (amount >= 100) {
        str += oneThruNineteen[ amount / 100] + " hundred ";
        str += numToStr(amount % 100);
    }
    else if (amount >= 20) {
        str += theDecades[  amount / 10 ];
        str += numToStr(amount % 10);
    }
    else {
        str += oneThruNineteen[ amount ];
    }
    return str;
}
```

It is possible to improve even further to add thousands, millions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The main body of could is really easy to be written as a recursive program:

```
final private  static String[] units = {"Zero","One","Two","Three","Four",
    "Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
    "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen",
    "Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};
final private static String[] tens = {"","","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty",
    "Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"};

public static String convert(Integer i) {
    if( i < 20)  return units[i];
    if( i < 100) return tens[i/10] + ((i % 10 > 0)? " " + convert(i % 10):"");
    if( i < 1000) return units[i/100] + " Hundred" + ((i % 100 > 0)?" and " + convert(i % 100):"");
    if( i < 1000000) return convert(i / 1000) + " Thousand " + ((i % 1000 > 0)? " " + convert(i % 1000):"") ;
    return convert(i / 1000000) + " Million " + ((i % 1000000 > 0)? " " + convert(i % 1000000):"") ;
}
```

Now just cover pence aswell:

```
public static String convert(Double i) {
    double pence = (int)((i-((int)i))*100);
    string result = convert((int)i);
    return pence.Equals(0d) ? result : result + " and " + pence " pence";
}
```