# Convert number to words

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers-to-words

I wrote this converter code. It can convert a number from 1-100 into words. It works perfectly, but it seems to be too complicated to me.

Can you tell me whether it's okay or not?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number;
    int first_digit;
    int second_digit;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    first_digit = number/10;
    second_digit = number%10;
    if(number >= 11 && number <= 20)
    {
        switch(number)
        {
            case 11:
                std::cout<<"eleven";
                break;

            case 12:
                std::cout<<"twelve";
                break;
            case 13:
                std::cout<<"thirteen";
                break;
            case 14:
                std::cout<<"fourteen";
                break;
            case 15:
                std::cout<<"fifteen";
                break;
            case 16:
                std::cout<<"sixteen";
                break;
            case 17:
                std::cout<<"seventeen";
                break;
            case 18:
                std::cout<<"eighteen";
                break;
            case 19:
                std::cout<<"nineteen";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(first_digit)
        {
            case 1:
                if(second_digit == 0)
                    std::cout<<"ten";
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout<<"twenty";
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout<< "thirty";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout<<"fourty";
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout<<"fifty";
                break;
            case 6:
                std::cout<<"sixty";
                break;
            case 7:
                std::cout<<"seventy";
                break;
            case 8: 
                std::cout <<"eighty";
                break;
            case 9:
                std::cout <<"ninety";
                break;
            case 10:
                std::cout <<"one hundred";
                break;
        }
        if(first_digit > 1 && number != 100) std::cout<<"-";
        switch(second_digit)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"one";
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout<<"two";
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout<<"three";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout<<"four";
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout<<"five";
                break;
            case 6:
                std::cout<<"six";
                break;
            case 7:
                std::cout<<"seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                std::cout<<"eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                std::cout<<"nine";
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never tackled such a problem before, so I'll proceed with this cautiously.

- You don't need to declare those three variables and then assign to them.  Instead, initialize them right away where they're first used.

  You can also move `number` right above the `cin` for slightly closer scope.

  ```
  std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
  int number;
  std::cin >> number;
  int first_digit = number/10;
  int second_digit = number%10;
  ```
- I suppose `switch` is an okay choice for this program.  Either way, the `switch` can still be condensed while making the program more modular (with functions).

  Here's what 11-20 could look like within its own function:

  ```
  std::string elevenThroughTwenty(unsigned int number)
  {
      switch (number)
      {
          case 11: return "eleven";
          // ...
          case 20: return "twenty"; // you forgot the 20 in your code

          // throw an exception if number not in the switch
          // include <stdexcept> to use this
          default: throw std::logic_error("Not 11 through 20");
      }
  }
  ```

  Separating them as such helps with readability, organization, and conciseness.  You will also need proper `default`s so that invalid numbers don't cause crippling errors.

Comment: Thank you :) but I have a question: what does O(1) mean?

Comment: @mitya221: Constant time. Meaning, one pass no matter what. Example: `arr[7] = 25`.

Comment: @Jamal I don't think switches are "constant time" in the way that you mean. A switch with N different cases will (I'm pretty sure) generate N different branch statements that the program would proceed through sequentially.

Comment: @alecbenzer: Noted.  The OP didn't know what O(1) meant anyway, so I've explained that.

Comment: @mitya221: As already brought to my attention, O(1) is not guaranteed here (but my comment still stands).  Also, most of the examples I've found on this use arrays.  I suppose it doesn't make a huge difference (although still different times), but it's up to you.  As for `switch`es in general, I'd at least make them as condensed (but readable) as possible.  They can take up much physical space.

Comment: Negative values being illegal is not considered a good enough reason to use `unsigned`. See discussion in comments [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70027/given-n-numbers-find-out-the-least-k-numbers-from-them/70031#70031).

Comment: @nwp: Fair enough, also given that my `default` would handle incorrect numbers. And this is an older answer, so I was less aware.  I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably make some arrays and do lookups in them instead of using switches: http://ideone.com/44IB0J

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

string toWords(int num) {
  if (num > 100 || num < 1) {
    throw "unsupported";
  }
  if (num == 100) {
    return "one hundred";
  }

  const string kSpecialCases[] = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
  if (10 <= num && num <= 19) {
    return kSpecialCases[num - 10];
  }

  const string kOnesPlaces[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
  const string kTensPlaces[] = {"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
  if (num < 10) {
    return kOnesPlaces[num - 1];
  } else if (num % 10 == 0) {
    return kTensPlaces[num / 10 - 2];
  } else {
    return kTensPlaces[num / 10 - 2] + " " + kOnesPlaces[num % 10 - 1];
  }
}

int main() {
  cout << toWords(1) << endl;
  cout << toWords(100) << endl;
  cout << toWords(12) << endl;
  cout << toWords(29) << endl;
  cout << toWords(46) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code will break on `20`

```
if(number >= 11 && number <= 20)
{
    switch(number)
    {
   ......
        case 19:
            std::cout<<"nineteen";
            break;
       /// No Twenty here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the problem making use of recursion. This works for any number between **0** (**zero**) and **999,999,999** (**nine hundred ninety nine million nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine**).

***Note:** Due to making use of initializer lists, this will only work in C++11.*

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

const std::vector<std::string> first14 = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen" };
const std::vector<std::string> prefixes = {"twen", "thir", "for", "fif", "six", "seven", "eigh", "nine"};

std::string inttostr( const unsigned int number )
{
    if( number <= 14 )
        return first14.at(number);
    if( number < 20 )
        return prefixes.at(number-12) + "teen";
    if( number < 100 ) {
        unsigned int remainder = number - (static_cast<int>(number/10)*10);
        return prefixes.at(number/10-2) + (0 != remainder ? "ty " + inttostr(remainder) : "ty");
    }
    if( number < 1000 ) {
        unsigned int remainder = number - (static_cast<int>(number/100)*100);
        return first14.at(number/100) + (0 != remainder ? " hundred " + inttostr(remainder) : " hundred");
    }
    if( number < 1000000 ) {
        unsigned int thousands = static_cast<int>(number/1000);
        unsigned int remainder = number - (thousands*1000);
        return inttostr(thousands) + (0 != remainder ? " thousand " + inttostr(remainder) : " thousand");
    }
    if( number < 1000000000 ) {
        unsigned int millions = static_cast<int>(number/1000000);
        unsigned int remainder = number - (millions*1000000);
        return inttostr(millions) + (0 != remainder ? " million " + inttostr(remainder) : " million");
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("inttostr() value too large");
}

int main()
{
    try {
        for( int i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++ )
            std::cout << i << " = " << inttostr(i) << std::endl;
    } catch( std::exception& ex ) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::vector<std::string> const names[]= {{"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
                                         "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" },
                                         {"-", "-", "twenty--", "thirty--", "forty--", "fifty--", "sixty--", "seventy--", "eighty--", "ninety--"}
                                        };

void print(int& count, int unit, int xx, std::string const& units)
{
    int                 div     = unit * (xx==0?1:10);
    int                 index   = count / div;
    int                 sub     = index * div * (index >=2 ? 1 : 0);
    std::string         name    = names[xx][index];

    if (name[name.size()-1] == '-') {
        name.erase(name.size()-1);
        index   = (count-sub)/unit;
        name.append(names[0][index]);
    }
    if (name != "") {
        std::cout << name << " " << units << " ";
    }
    count   = count - (count/unit*unit);
}
void printNumber(int number)
{
    if (number == 0) {
        std::cout << "zero";
        return;
    }
    print(number, 1000000, 0, "million");
    print(number, 100000,  0, "hundred");
    print(number, 1000,    1, "thousand");
    print(number, 100,     0, "hundred");
    print(number, 1,       1, "");
}
int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    printNumber(number);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
> ./a.out
845
eight hundred forty-five
> ./a.out
999999
nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
> ./a.out
1000001
one million one
```