# Given n numbers, find out the least k numbers from them

Tags: c++

I have been solving the following problem:

> Given n numbers find out the least k numbers from them. For example, if there are 8 numbers like 5,6,3,4,7,8,9,-1. For k = 3 the result will be -1,3,4.

I implemented it in the following way:

1. make heap with first k numbers
2. traverse the rest k-n numbers

   1. if heapMax > any of the k numbers then
   2. swap
3. return heap containing k numbers

Can you please review my code and provide me with feedback?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getKLeastNumbers(std::vector<int> &nums, int k)
{
    std::vector<int> tmpNums;

    if(k<=0 || k > nums.size())
    {
        return tmpNums;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        tmpNums.push_back(nums.at(i));
    }
    std::make_heap(tmpNums.begin(), tmpNums.end());

    for(int i=k; i<nums.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tmpNums.front() > nums.at(i))
        {
            int tmp = nums.at(i);

            nums.at(i) = tmpNums.front();

            std::pop_heap(tmpNums.begin(),tmpNums.end());
            tmpNums.pop_back();

            tmpNums.push_back(tmp);
            std::push_heap(tmpNums.begin(), tmpNums.end());
        }
    }

    return tmpNums;
}

int main()
{
    // test codes
    std::vector<int>nums;
    nums.push_back(56);
    nums.push_back(5);
    nums.push_back(6);
    nums.push_back(60);
    nums.push_back(-6);
    nums.push_back(3);
    nums.push_back(600);

    nums = getKLeastNumbers(nums,1);

    for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<nums.at(i)<<std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<int>nums2;
    nums2.push_back(56);

    nums2 = getKLeastNumbers(nums2,-1);

    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Test set 2 "<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<nums2.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<<nums2.at(i)<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you can use C++11.

- Use initializer lists:

  ```
  std::vector<int>nums;
  nums.push_back(56);
  nums.push_back(5);
  nums.push_back(6);
  nums.push_back(60);
  nums.push_back(-6);
  nums.push_back(3);
  nums.push_back(600);
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  std::vector<int> nums = {56, 5, 6, 60, -6, 3, 600};
  ```
- Use range based for:

  ```
  nums = getKLeastNumbers(nums, 1);

  for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
  {
      std::cout<<nums.at(i)<<std::endl;
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  for (auto &i : getKLeastNumbers(nums, 1))
      std::cout << i << '\n';
  ```
- Do not hide bugs. If you detect that someone used your function wrong tell them instead of letting them wonder why the return value doesn't make sense.

  ```
  if(k<=0 || k > nums.size())
  {
      return tmpNums;
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  assert(k <= 0 && k > nums.size());
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (k <=0 || k > nums.size())
      throw std::range_error("k must be bigger than 0 and less than num's size");
  ```
- You seem to be using the heap functions correctly, however, there are functions more suitable for that. I would pick `std::partial_sort`.

  ```
  std::vector<int> getKLeastNumbers(std::vector<int> &nums, int k)
  {
      std::partial_sort(std::begin(nums), std::begin(nums) + k, std::end(nums));
      return { std::begin(nums), std::begin(nums) + k };
  }
  ```
- The declaration for `getKLeastNumbers` is a bit strange. `nums` is not `const` and gets modified which feels unexpected. Why can I not use `getKLeastNumbers` on a `const std::vector`?. I would prefer a `const &` to preserve the original value, allow `const vector` and to be able to initialize `nums` with an initializer list directly.

Comment: I'd also suggest that the second argument to `getKLeastNumbers()` should be `unsigned` rather than `int`.  A whole class of possible errors is rendered impossible by that small change.

Comment: @Edward I am not convinced that this is good advice. First you can still pass negative numbers which become huge positive numbers which does not help reducing error potential. Secondly I tend to calculate differences of sizes which would make me clutter the code with casts. I would even prefer `sizeof` to return a signed number to prevent `if (sizeof(int) - 4 < 0)` to do something unexpected.

Comment: If your proposed function is called as `getKLeastNumbers(nums, -3)` it throws `std::bad_alloc` and crashes on my machine.  To fix this, you need to compare `k` with `nums.size()` which is an unsigned quantity; hence `k` should also be unsigned.

Comment: @Edward: I disagree that it removes the error. But rather it hides errors (if you are not validating already) because of auto conversion. if the interface is only takes unsigned int and I call it `getKLeastNumbers(data, -1);` it still compiles just fine. It will run just fine and the `-1` silently becomes some big number. There is no magic bullet you have to validate your input.

Comment: @LokiAstari: of course it's no magic bullet. The point is that *the interface itself* should help indicate how to correctly use the function.  There's simply no benefit to using `int` and many disadvantages.  If I encountered this error and traced to this function in a debugger, I wouldn't have to step through and debug this function -- it would be clear from the interface what the error is.

Comment: @Edward: Sure use `unsigned int`. That's fine. But `A whole class of possible errors is rendered impossible` is not true. You still have to validate the input

Comment: @LokiAstari: the class of errors I was referring to is "correctly handling negative numbers."

Comment: @Edward: Which is just a sub class of handling numbers in the correct range. Which you still have to do in this case. Changing the input type does not help in solving the problem; only in moving it to the other end of the spectrum.

Comment: There was a great talk by Bjarne Stroustrup at going native last year. Is it worth using `unsigned number` for anything. Do they really buy you anything. Answer no. An extra bit. Now worth it. The consensus is that you should use signed for everything unless you are using the int for bit flags then use unsigned otherwise signed. They also admitted that the choice of the standard library using unsigned in most places was a mistake.

Comment: see: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything its at the 40 minutes and 19 second mark the bjarne talks about unsigned ints.

Comment: at 44 minutes 30 second mark Herb Sutter says Quote: "Unfortunately is a mistake in the STL and standard that we use use unsigned integers".

Comment: The general consensus from the panel (of C++ luminaries) was that using unsigned is the source of more bugs (Bjarne said it the others were all nodding). As a consequence it is always best to use int (signed) were possible only use unsigned in very rare cases.

Comment: @nwp Thanks for your suggestions. But shouldn't it be out _of_range ? According to standard out_of_range: The class out_of_range defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an argument value not in its expected range.

Answer (score 7):

There are several things that you could improve, especially with regards to containers usage:

- If you can use C++11 or a more recent version of the C++ standard, then you can use an [initializer list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) to push elements into your `std::vector` when your construct it:

  ```
  std::vector<int> nums = { 56, 5, 6, 60, -6, 3, 600 };
  ```
- If you don't explicitly need indices, then use iterators to iterate over containers. It helps to write more generic code. Here is one of your loops converted to iterators. I also used the C++11 [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to make it even clearer:

  ```
  for (int& elem: nums)
  {
      if (tmpNums.front() > elem)
      {
          int tmp = elem;
          elem = tmpNums.front();

          std::pop_heap(tmpNums.begin(),tmpNums.end());
          tmpNums.pop_back();

          tmpNums.push_back(tmp);
          std::push_heap(tmpNums.begin(), tmpNums.end());
      }
  }
  ```
- By the way, in this loop, instead of popping the last element and pushing back a new one, you could simply assign the new value to the last element of the container:

  ```
  std::pop_heap(tmpNums.begin(),tmpNums.end());
  tmpNums.back() = tmp;
  std::push_heap(tmpNums.begin(), tmpNums.end());
  ```
- Instead of using a loop to initialize `tmpNums` with the \$k\$ first elements of `nums`, you can use the [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which takes two iterators:

  ```
  std::vector<int> tmpNums(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+k);
  ```

  This will create `tmpNums` and initialize it by copying the elements in the range `[vec[0], vec[k])`, which is exactly what you want.
- I don't especially like this condition to return early:

  ```
  if(k<=0 || k > nums.size())
  {
      return tmpNums;
  }
  ```

  In my opinion, calling the function and asking to treat a negative number of elements or a number of elements greater than the one available is a logic error and should fail instead of returning an empty `std::vector` which doesn't really help the user. I would probably replace the condition by hard assertions:

  ```
  assert(k > 0);
  assert(k <= nums.size());
  ```

  It is important for the user to know why that fails. Therefore, I would also document these as preconditions in the function documentation.

Comment: Asserts are for things that will never happen in production. I.E. you validate your pre-conditions are holding in your test environment (in production asserts do nothing). For things that can happen but should not something else is more appropriate (potentially exception).

Comment: @LokiAstari Frankly, in our case, if you use the function correctly, there should not be errors here. Passing a negative `k` clearly shows that you did something wrong, that won't appear at random and you should be able to catch the problem during the test phase.

Comment: Assuming at some point this will be user input you really need to validate and use another method other than assert (probably outside the function were the user inputs the data). My point is that assert is not the same as validation. assert is used to validate correctness of the calling function while testing the code.

Answer (score 6):

Since there are already a couple of reviews, I won't repeat that advice, but can add a few other things.

### Include relevant `#include` files

The code uses `std::push_heap` which is defined in `<algorithm>` but the code doesn't include that file.  It should.

### Use appropriate types

Because you're looking for the least \$k\$ numbers from a collection, it doesn't make much sense to ask for a negative number of them.  For that reason, I'd recommend making `k` an `unsigned` parameter.

### Simplify the code by using standard operations

A simpler way to write this function would be this:

```
template <typename T>
T getKLeast(T collection, unsigned k)
{
    std::sort(collection.begin(), collection.end());
    if (k > collection.size())
        return collection;
    return T{collection.begin(), collection.begin()+k};
}
```

This makes a copy of the passed type, sorts it, and then returns only the first \$k\$ items.  Also, I've used a template so that it works just as well with a `std::list` or `std::vector<float>` or even `std::vector<std::string>`.

### Don't use `std::endl` if `'\n'` will do

Using `std::endl` emits a `\n` and flushes the stream.  Unless you really need the stream flushed, you can improve the performance of the code by simply emitting `'\n'` instead of using the potentially more computationally costly `std::endl`.

### Simplify the test code by overloading `operator<<`

If we define this function:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<int>&collection)
{
    for (const auto &item : collection)
        std::cout << item << ", ";
    return out;
}
```

The `main` code can get really simple now:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int>nums{56, 5, 6, 60, -6, 3, 600};

    cout << getKLeast(nums, 3) << '\n'
         << getKLeast(nums, 2) << '\n'
         << getKLeast(nums, 0) << '\n'
         << getKLeast(nums, 100) << '\n';
}
```

#### sample output

On my machine, here's what that program prints:

```
-6, 3, 5, 
-6, 3, 

-6, 3, 5, 6, 56, 60, 600,
```

Comment: Regarding `std::endl` take a look at what Scott Meyers [has to say about it](http://aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/novdec95.pdf). Also my `partial_sort` beats your `sort` ;D

Comment: @nwp: regarding `partial_sort` vs. `sort`.  If you're thinking that `partial_sort` is faster, you should test that assumption.  Testing here and [by others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364848/is-partial-sort-copy-the-fastest-c-partial-sort) shows `sort` is typically much faster.

Comment: Don't like the idea of defining a serializer for such a generic container. You may accidentally hide errors. I would create a specific printer wrapper that the user must explicitly use to prevent accidental printing. `std::cout << VectorPrinter(getKLeast(nums, 3)) << "\n";`

Comment: @Edward I did a [benchmark](http://www.chartgo.com/share.do?id=80d2e5b0aa) of my own based on the one you linked. `partial_sort` is faster if the percentage of the data you sort is small whereas `sort` is faster if the percentage is high. Turns out the break even point is around 23%. The test you linked always uses 50% which makes `partial_sort` look bad. I felt like `k` would be small compared to `n` for this problem, but a better solution would be to check if `k < n * .23` and pick the sorting function accordingly. I suppose the break even percentage depends on the system and data types.

Answer (score 5):

A more concise way of displaying the vectors, without the use of any loops, is to use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
std::copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n");
```

```
std::copy(nums2.begin(), nums2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n");
```

This doesn't require any C++11, in case you don't have access to it.

Comment: Would you recommend to always do this? If so, why? I can't seem to find a liking to use `copy` for printing.

Comment: @nwp: That may depend on readability and what is available to you.  There are other ways of printing storage containers, and I'm not suggesting that this is the best way.  I'm not too keen to always using a loop just for displaying something.